# Nested for loops and looping through subfolders, is this legal? .bat script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get a feel for .bat files and I am trying to modify a script so it can loop through every subfolder in a directory and delete certain file types within each folder.

Here is an idea of what I currently have and I would like to know if it is legal or not to do something like this:

```
*Creates "deletethese.txt" via sql command*
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%v IN (deletethese.txt) DO (
    For /R C:\Users\Public\Documents\ %%G IN (%%V) DO ECHO Deleting File %%G
    For /R C:\Users\Public\Documents\ %%G IN (%%V) DO DEL "%%G"
)
```

Basically it is taking the txt file it generates from the sql command and loops through it and takes it's contents. I need this script to go through each subfolder in the directory and check if those contents exist and if they do, echo that variable and then delete that content. Also, do I need the "%%G IN (%%V)" or can I leave out the parameter and just use %%V.

I am not sure if this is the best way to go about this or not or if I am even on the right track, that is why I am here.

Thanks for any help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need this script to go through each subfolder in the directory and check if those contents exist and if they do, echo that variable and then delete that content.

As I understand it, you just need to confirm a filename specified in `deletethese.txt` exists in a folder (`C:\Users\Public\Documents`) and if so, delete it.

That being the case, you can accomplish this with the following `FOR` loop:

```
*Creates "deletethese.txt" via sql command*
SET "PathToCheck=C:\Users\Public\Documents"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%v IN (deletethese.txt) DO (
    REM Verify file exists before attempting to delete.
    IF EXIST "%PathToCheck%\%%v" (
        ECHO Deleting File %%v
        DEL "%PathToCheck%\%%v"
    )
)
```

However, if you need to locate files with the specified name *within* the specified folder, you can do this:

```
*Creates "deletethese.txt" via sql command*
SET "PathToCheck=C:\Users\Public\Documents"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%v IN (deletethese.txt) DO (
    REM Locate all files with the name within the path.
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`DIR "%PathToCheck%\%%v" /B /S /A:-D`) DO (
        ECHO Deleting File %%A
        DEL "%%A"
    )
)
```

Comment: Man, it just seems so simple if the syntax and command knowledge is there. Thanks a lot, this clears things up quite a bit!

Comment: @namedoc - Glad to help. Batch programming takes a bit of getting used to, but it surprisingly powerful once you get your head around it.

Comment: Ok so quick question as I may have read the initial answer wrong. The directory I am working in for example: "C:\Users\Public\Documents" has multiple subfolders (test1, test2, test3, test4, etc..). Each of those subfolders have the filenames that get put inside of the "deletethese.txt" from the sql command, which is why I thought I had to use the /r for loop to loop through each subfolder and each file within those subfolders. Is that correct?

Comment: @namedoc - Your existing batch file was close to doing this (@Magoo comments on this below). However, the second version posted leverages the `DIR` function to accomplish the subdirectly search for matches. Personally, this "clicks" with me better than the `FOR /R` syntax.

Comment: Ok I'm following. Could you explain this line "FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`DIR "%PathToCheck%\%%v" /B /S /A:-D`)" as I am just missing the common knowledge on the DIR syntax I think.

Comment: @namedoc - That command says to look in the `PathToCheck` for files matching `%%v`. Exclude directory names (`/A:-D`), look in subfolders (`/S`), and return _only_ the file name (`/B`). The results of this are then processed by the `FOR /F` loop.

Comment: My knowledge on FOR /R is that it loops through every folder and file in the directory that you provide.

Comment: @namedoc - Yes it will. As I mentioned earlier, I prefer the `DIR` command over the `FOR /R` semantics.

Comment: Got it! I am going to see if I can get the script working with both and see which I prefer. I appreciate the ongoing help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68757/discussion-between-namedoc-and-jason-faulkner).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your original code was very nearly correct.

Batch is largely insensitive to character-case **except** for the metavariable (loop-control variable) %%v/V in your case.

So all you'd need to do was make your `%%v`s all the same case.

As a By-the-by,

```
For /R C:\Users\Public\Documents\ %%G IN (%%V) DO ECHO Deleting File %%G
```

is better as

```
For /R "C:\Users\Public\Documents\" %%G IN (%%V) DO ECHO Deleting File %%G
```

because the quotes would *need* to be there if the directory-name contained <kbd>Space</kbd> or other separators.

And... your original would have listed all the files, then commenced deleting them; possibly better as

```
For /R C:\Users\Public\Documents\ %%G IN (%%V) DO ECHO Deleting File "%%G"&del "%%G"
```

where `&` is the inline statement-separator.

Comment: I've always preferred enumerating a `DIR /B` result over a `FOR /R`. Is there any _real_ advantage of one over the other?

Comment: @JasonFaulkner: I rarely use `for /r` but there certainly **is** a difference for a plain `for` which may or may not be shared by other `for` options. Using the `dir` approach first builds a list in memory and then processes the list whereas `for` gets the next file regardless. The consequence is that if the process itself modifies the directory by adding a new file then there is a chance that the new file will be processed as it's now appeared and is next in the directory but `dir` will not have any such new file in its list.